# Numpy.isin filtering for multiple columns in Structured numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to mask/filter a structured numpy array if the rows are present in another structured numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

dt = {'names':['A', 'B', 'C'],
        'formats': [np.int64, np.int64, np.dtype('U8')]}

arr = np.array([
        (1, 100, 'ab'),
        (2, 800, 'ax'),
        (3, 700, 'asb'),
        (4, 100, 'ab'),
        (5, 500, 'hfg')
], dtype = dt)

dt2 = {'names':['D', 'E', 'F'],
        'formats': [np.int64, np.dtype('U8'), np.dtype('U8')]}

arr2 = np.array([
        (100, 'ab', 'cff'),
        (100, 'cd', 'sdf'),
        (500, 'hfg', 'cff'),
        (500, 'xx', 'asd')
], dtype = dt2)

print(arr)
print(arr2)

arr3 = arr[np.isin(arr[['B','C']], arr2[['D', 'E']])]

print(arr3)
```

Element wise comparison failed on this program and a empty result is returned. The result I'm expecting is -

```
[(1,100,'ab'), (4, 100, 'ab'), (5, 500, 'hfg')]
```

The corresponding columns must match. Comparing the columns separately will give wrong results. Is there a way to perform this in numpy. **Please don't suggest Pandas or other library based solutions**.

Comment: So the condition is if the last two elements are in any of the tuples in arr2? And why do you use tuples instead of array to assign the elements in the first place?

Comment: The dtypes have to be the ame.  You can't compare different subsets of columns.

Comment: You can make the arrays without the ugly `np.append`.  Use lists of tuples.

Comment: Dos `isin` run, or does it raise an error?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew, he's using tuples to creat structured arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj **isin** can be used for single dimensions

Comment: That's not my point. `isin` in 2d mode actual creates a 1d structured array. But you are comparing arrays with different dtypes.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error, which you forgot to post (why?):

```
In [105]: arr[np.isin(arr[['B','C']], arr2[['D', 'E']])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [105] in <cell line: 1>
    arr[np.isin(arr[['B','C']], arr2[['D', 'E']])]
  File <__array_function__ internals>:180 in isin
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py:739 in isin
    return in1d(element, test_elements, assume_unique=assume_unique,
  File <__array_function__ internals>:180 in in1d
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py:612 in in1d
    mask |= (ar1 == a)
TypeError: Cannot compare structured arrays unless they have a common dtype.  I.e. `np.result_type(arr1, arr2)` must be defined.
```

`isin` requires the ability to compare the elements of the arrays.  With different `dtypes` that's impossible.

```
In [106]: arr[['B','C']].dtype, arr2[['D', 'E']].dtype
Out[106]: 
(dtype({'names': ['B', 'C'], 'formats': ['<i8', '<U8'], 'offsets': [8, 16], 'itemsize': 48}),
 dtype({'names': ['D', 'E'], 'formats': ['<i8', '<U8'], 'offsets': [0, 8], 'itemsize': 72}))
```

Just for reference

```
In [107]: arr.dtype, arr2.dtype
Out[107]: 
(dtype([('A', '<i8'), ('B', '<i8'), ('C', '<U8')]),
 dtype([('D', '<i8'), ('E', '<U8'), ('F', '<U8')]))
```

It does work if I `repack_fields` and `rename_fields`:

```
In [114]: np.isin(rf.repack_fields(arr[['B','C']]), 
     rf.rename_fields(rf.repack_fields(arr2[['D', 'E']]),{'D':'B','E':'C'}))
Out[114]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True])
```